# intellij- how to remove "bracket" from the project name?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have a project in Intellij and I have a tree structure on the left hand side which list out the project name,folders,files etc.

And at the top of the main project, I have my project name in the format of:

```
 Project Name [XXX] C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\ProjectName
```

The problem is [XXX] where I can't find any resources as to what it is and I want to rename it or remove it completely. Any idea what do I need to change?

What is that bracket name represents?

Things I have tried:

Renaming the .iml file

Renaming project name in Project Structure

Comment: the maven `artifactId`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the **module name** that can be configured automatically from the `pom.xml` `<artifactId>` property or defined manually:

[image: module name]

You can switch the view to some other mode like **Packages** or **Project Files** to not display the module names.

Comment: It works but I noticed if I changed it manually as shown in your picture, it generates a new .iml file for the new name and the old .iml file still remains. What is going on?

Comment: If your project is not Maven or Gradle based, you can delete the old .iml file, otherwise it will be generated again on the next refresh.

Comment: That's what happening to mine, it's maven based and it keeps generating. How do i stop this?

Comment: You can't change it for the Maven project. Module name will be generated from the artifactID.

Comment: So what's my next step looking into?

Comment: See the second part of the answer to change the project view mode.

Comment: Oh I mean the error for not able to deploy my project.

Comment: Please comment in the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 23):

This is due to `rename` of module not done properly, you or Intellij IDEA would have changed only `directory` name.

The easiest way to fix this issue is press `shift key+f6` / Right click on module `Refactor >> Rename` and select `Rename module`, give name same as `Project/directory`.

Immediately you will see bracket with older module name disappear.

Below is snippet and option to choose highlighted:

[image: Rename module]

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure all the other comments were valid for other peoples specific issues, but only this one fixed my case.

Comment: @yiati , same in my case. went through few solution but this one was easy & quick solution.

Comment: This solution works until you stop and start PHPStorm. Then the bracketed name reappears. I resolved it by going into the main project folder where all my project files were stored, via Windows (in my case), and I removed the .idea folder. I closed and reopened PHPStorm and the bracketed name was gone. It ain't a pretty solution, but it worked for me

Comment: @AlanN my case i wasn't using PHPStrom. Good point remane the .idea dir name itself.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to resolve this issue was similar to the previous poster. After changing the module name in Project Structure/Modules (command + ;), I was still seeing the old module name within the project name. What made a difference for me was assigning the rootProject.name to the new module name in settings.gradle:

[changing module name in settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4trfq.png)

Answer (score 1):

if you did rename project name and module. **just try sync project with gradle. file -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.**
it will update everything and remove that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gradle in your project and the Rename option in IntellijIDEA didn't help as in other answers, try to change parameter rootProject.name in file settings.gradle:

[image: settings.gradle here]

Comment: Try to add what the change in parameter should be and why. Also any suggested link/docs would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The name between brackets is the module name accessible in Intellij by pressing:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Besides `<artifactId>` in pom.xml also intellij's project specific iml file name is taken in sequence(intellij 2020.3).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.